# MongoDB many small uploads vs one large upload

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using a MongoDB for storing data. I'm putting in data that is chunked nicely, but could also be easily combined into one large chunk and pushed all in one go.

Is there an advantage to pushing all the data in one go? Or should I push each chunk individually?

Also, are there any restrictions on how much data I can push in one go? Pushing everything at once would be ~30MB, while each chunk is only ~10KB. In either case, I will be storing the same number of documents (<1KB per doc). I'm using pymongo, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using gridfs type storage, or storing regular documents? Keep in mind that an individual document can only be a maximum of 16MB in size.

Comment: @TomSwifty Storing regular documents, with each chunk consisting of multiple documents.

Comment: So to clarify, you're wondering if it's more efficient to do fewer inserts with many documents, compared to many single document inserts or something like that right?

Comment: @TomSwifty Basically, yeah

Comment: How are you consuming the documents/chunks?

Comment: @WiredPrairie What do you mean by consuming? If you are talking about what I do after the data is in Mongo, I don't think that matters because whether I push in chunks or all at once the collection will be in the same state afterward.

Answer (score 3):

There are three primary considerations:

1. The overhead in sending the documents over the wire in smaller batches.  e.g., How much more data do you need to send to send the documents.
2. How much additional latency is there is sending more batches due to waiting for the inserts to be acknowledged.
3. The fact that a large message with more document take more time to perform the insert on the server leading to periods were the server appears to "lock-up".

Size overhead:

The insert message sent have a fixes overhead of 20 bytes plus the length of the "." string.  There is a limit to the size of a single message in the tens of MB range so you you can save some data transfer space but the overhead ratio is already negligible for a 1KB document.

Latency:

Depending on the "network distance" of the client to the server this could have a much bigger impact.  The non-asynchronous drivers will send the insert message and then wait for a reply.  That includes the time to do the insert and the time to send the message to the server and receive the reply.  Even on a fast 1/4 ms round trip local network the sending of 3,000 messages (30MB/10KB) results in 750 ms of wait time.  If the client is "remote" the and has a 10 ms ping time then we are waiting for 30 seconds. Asynchronous drivers can fill the wait time with sending more request.

Server Lock-up:

As you insert more documents in one batch the server will take and hold the database lock for a longer period of time.  That will stop all other interaction with the database while the write is done (including updating indexes etc.  Depending on you workload this induced pause while the server performs the write could cause unwanted problems for other writers and readers.

Lastly, there is a major downside to batching the inserts: If any of the inserts fails you will have no idea which failed.  The server can return an error but will not say which document failed.  You can have the server "continue on error" but that only makes the situation marginally better.

I would encourage you to have a look at the [Motor](https://github.com/mongodb/motor/) extension to the Python driver.  It should allow you to:

1. Over come the latency issue by sending multiple requests on the same connection without waiting for the reply to each request.
2. Allow you to send each insert as a separate request so you know what happens for each.
3. And allows other reads and writes to naturally interleave with the writes you are generating.

HTH, Rob

Full Disclosure: I work on the [Java Asynchronous Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/motor/) but any asynchronous driver should be able to provide the benefits a list above.